# Let $G(V,E)$ be an un-directed, un-connected graph. Prove that $\bar G$ is connected, And its Diameter is at most $2$.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $G(V,E)$ be an un-directed, un-connected graph. Prove that $\bar G$ is connected, and that its diameter is at most $2$.

I've started by writing myself some guidelines:

1. Two vertices will be neighbors in $\bar G$ if and only if they weren't neighbors at $G$.
2. Undirected means that exists $u,v\in V$ so there's no track between them.

So I need to prove:

1. $\bar G$ connected
2. $\bar G$ diameter is 2 at most.

I guess that for (1) i need to prove that for every $u,v\in V$, I can find a track between them. Or, In some way prove that there are at least $n-1$ edges.
And for (2) i just don't know.

So i'm pretty much stuck, I can see the logic behind it [been drawing some examples], But I can't see how can I 'merge' between looking at a vertex in $G$ and then in $\bar G$, I know this might be pretty easy. But i just can't 'see' it.

Thanks.

Comment: How is it duplicate? How about the second part of the question?

Comment: If you follow my advice to see linked questions, [that answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/340814/5887) would help realizing that in $\bar G$ the shortest path is at most of the length $2$.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

[Dr. Math – Connected Graph](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222050133/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52260.html)

Comment: Thanks, That actually really helped for the first part.

Comment: You can use it for the second part: if you look at the second proof, they explain why there's always a path of length 2 between any two non-adjacent vertices in $\bar G$